# Can't get parsec to parse "."

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I was following along the Write yourself a scheme tut and was just about to complete it until i ran into an error where i can't load files.

```
=> (load "stdlib.shm")
Parse error at "lisp" (line 33, column 15):
unexpected "."
expecting space, letter, "\"", "#", "'", "(", "#\\" or digit
```

I have tried reworking the parsers but nothing seems to work.
here is the parser's code:

```
symbol :: Parser Char
symbol = oneOf "!$%&|*+-/:<=>?@^_~"

spaces :: Parser ()
spaces = skipMany1 space

escapedChars :: Parser Char
escapedChars = char '\\' >>
               oneOf "\\\"nrt" >>=
               \c -> return $ case c of
                                '\\' -> c
                                '"'  -> c
                                'n'  -> '\n'
                                'r'  -> '\r'
                                't'  -> '\t'

parseExpr :: Parser Lval
parseExpr = parseAtom
            <|> parseString
            <|> parseBool
            <|> parseQuoted
            <|> parseListStructure
            <|> try parseCharacter
            <|> try parseFloat
            <|> try parseNumber

-- Parse String of syntax: "<chars | digits | symbols>"
parseString :: Parser Lval
parseString = do char '"'
                 s <- many (escapedChars <|> (noneOf ['\\', '"']))
                 char '"'
                 (return . String) s

-- Parse single character of syntax: '<char>'
parseCharacter :: Parser Lval
parseCharacter = string "#\\" >>
                 many1 letter >>=
                 \s -> return $ case (map toLower s) of
                                 "space" -> Character ' '
                                 "newline" -> Character '\n'
                                 [x] -> Character x

-- Parse Atom (Symbol) may contain any one of chars in symbols
parseAtom :: Parser Lval
parseAtom = do first <- letter <|> symbol
               rest <- many $ letter <|> digit <|> symbol
               (return . Atom) $ first:rest

{- Parse any numerical form of these, where the prefix is sign of base.
(36674...,
 #d36674...,
 #x8F42...,
 #o107502...,
 #b1000111101000010...) -}
parseNumber :: Parser Lval
parseNumber = parsePlainNumber <|> parseRadixNumber

parsePlainNumber :: Parser Lval
parsePlainNumber = many1 digit >>= (return . Number . read)

parseRadixNumber :: Parser Lval
parseRadixNumber = char '#' >>
                   (parseDecimal
                   <|> parseHex
                   <|> parseOct
                   <|> parseBin)

parseDecimal :: Parser Lval
parseDecimal = do  char 'd'
                   x <- many1 digit
                   (return . Number . read) x

parseHex :: Parser Lval
parseHex = char 'x' >> many1 hexDigit >>=
           \x -> (return . Number) $ hex2Int x

parseOct :: Parser Lval
parseOct = char 'o' >> many1 octDigit >>=
           \x -> (return . Number) $ oct2Int x

parseBin :: Parser Lval
parseBin = char 'b' >> (many1 $ oneOf "10") >>=
           \x -> (return . Number) $ bin2Int x

hex2Int x = fst $ head $ readHex x
oct2Int x = fst $ head $ readOct x
bin2Int s = sum $ map (\(i,x) -> i*(2^x)) $ zip [0..] $ map p (reverse s)
  where p '0' = 0
        p '1' = 1

-- Parse floats of syntax: <digits>.<digits>
parseFloat :: Parser Lval
parseFloat = do x <- many1 digit
                char '.'
                y <- many1 digit
                (return . Float . read) $ x ++ "." ++ y

-- Parse booleans syntax: (#t, #f)
parseBool :: Parser Lval
parseBool = char '#' >> oneOf "tf" >>=
             \c -> return (case c of
                            't' -> Bool True
                            'f' -> Bool False)

-- Parsing anytype of list structure here
parseListStructure = do char '('
                        x <- parseList <|> parseDottedList
                        char ')'
                        return x

parseList :: Parser Lval
parseList = liftM List $ sepBy parseExpr spaces

parseDottedList :: Parser Lval
parseDottedList = do x <- endBy parseExpr spaces
                     xs <- char '.' >> spaces >> parseExpr
                     return $ DottedList x xs

-- Parsing quoted expressions
parseQuoted :: Parser Lval
parseQuoted = char '\'' >> parseExpr >>=
              \x -> return $ List [Atom "quote", x]
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if the file doesn't exist? If not, we need to see more code.

Comment: No if the file is non existent then i just get a "openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)"

Comment: It's encountering an error when parsing the file. We need to see the first expression (at least!) of the file (try to narrow it down as much as possible while still producing the error), and maybe the loading code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) (In the comments above) I found the problem. It was a syntax error in the stdlib.shm file:

```
(define (list . lst) lst)
```

Comment: Glad you found it. Next time, you should probably consider validating your test case with an established Scheme implementation first! Many people like Racket, particularly because it has a really nice IDE and debugger, but you can use Guile or whatever if you have it lying around.